# Linux socket use SO_BINDTODEVICE but with specified IP address

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I got a program which does

```
    ...
    /* Only rx/tx packets on the interface */
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, name, strlen(name))) {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

for each given ethernet interface and uses UDP.
I want every interface to use the same IP I specified (for example: 50.0.0.1/24).
So that packets coming out from eth0 tell "my source IP is 50.0.0.1"
and packets from eth1 tell the same("source IP: 50.0.0.1").
Both receiving and sending in required.

Is there any way to achieve this?
I've tried

```
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("50.0.0.1");
    ...
    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

but it won't work (error: cannot assign IP address) unless I set an unrelated interface's IP to 50.0.0.1.
After that, the packets coming out say "source IP: 50.0.0.1" but sending packets with "source IP: 50.0.0.X" to the machine (which runs the above program), it will not receive any.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not notice there's an edit button and I thought this question was fixed and screwed after I post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind a socket to an interface and an IP at the same time, only one or the other. If an interface is bound, its IP gets used. If an IP is bound, its interface gets used.

And, you can't use `bind()` to set a source IP that does not belong to the bound interface.

On some platforms (Linux, etc), you can use `sendmsg()` with `IP_PKTINFO` to specify a source IP for outgoing packets. However, the OS will lookup and use the interface that belongs to the specified IP, which could be different than the bound interface, so this doesn't address your issue.

So, you will likely have to use a RAW socket and send your UDP packets with a custom IP header, then you can populate that header however you want.

Comment: Okay... I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
ip addr add 50.0.0.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 50.0.0.1/24 dev eth1
```

Start the program which does

```
setsocketopt(fd1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth0", strlen("eth0"));
...
setsocketopt(fd2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth1", strlen("eth1"));
```

Works like a charm.
They all send packets with source IP "50.0.0.1".
And are able receive packets belong to 50.0.0.0/24 network.
The output packets will not go to the wrong interface due to the socket is bond to specific interface(SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alright then! :)